# Text and percentages in labels of pie chart

Tags: r, label, pie-chart

Hi I'm doing a basic pie chart, but when I do it only the "names" appear as the labels. I want the labels to be the names+percentage.

so I have:

```
reasons=prop.table(table(data$Reason[data$Stops %in% 1]))*100
```

with this I get:

```
DP 64
UV 20
TC 16
```

then

```
pie(reasons, color=rainbow(reasons), main="Distribution of Reasons")
```

With that I only get the pie with the labels `DP`, `UV` and `TC`.

What should I add to get `DP 64%`, `UV 20%`, `TC 16%` in the labels?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use the `labels` argument in `pie`

```
library(dplyr)
df <- read.table(text =
    "DP 64
UV 20
TC 16") %>%
    setNames(c("Reason", "Value")) %>%
    mutate(Percentage = sprintf("%s %3.1f%%", Reason, Value / sum(Value) * 100))
with(df, pie(
    Value,
    labels = Percentage,
    col = rainbow(length(Value)),
    main = "Distribution of Reasons"))
```

[image]